# awk columns based on condition with header

Tags: awk

I have a text file like below.

```
variable1  
10 20 30  
40 50 60

variable2  
2 4 40  
3 2 1

variable3   
2 4 2  
3 2 1
```

If col3>20 the output should be like below with header(variable1/2) values

```
variable1  
10 20 30  
40 50 60  

variable2  
2 4 40
```

If there is no match nothing should be printed and no header as well.

Comment: Does `--` occur in every header and never in the data rows? Do you want the header to be printed in case no following row matches the condition col3>20? Please [edit] your question to answer. Do you require the empty lines to be printed in the output?

Comment: Variable1/2 just a header . I have edited the question.  It does not have nany relation with data rows. If there is no match nothing should be printed

Comment: How to distinguish the "header" lines from data lines? Are the data lines always 3 columns, and the header lines always only one word? Anything else to distinguish header from data?

Comment: yes Data line always 3 columns and header always one word. Condition match should be there for data rows only and if match print header and data rows

Comment: Add all the clarification you wrote in comments to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my interpretation of the requirements

```
 awk 'NF==1 { head=$0; printed=0; }
      NF==3 && $3>20 { 
          if(!printed) {
              printed=1;
              if(firstdone)print ""; else firstdone=1;
              print head
          }
          print
      }' inputfile
```

or shorter variants

```
awk 'NF==1 { head=$0; printed=0; }
     NF==3 && $3>20 {
         if(!printed++) {
             if(firstdone++)print "";
             print head
         };
         print
     }' inputfile
```

```
awk 'NF==1 { head=$0; }
     NF==3 && $3>20 {
         if(head) {
             if(firstdone++)print "";
             print head;
             head=""
         };
         print
     }' inputfile
```

With input

```
variable1
10 20 30
40 50 60

variable2
2 4 40
3 2 1

variable3
10 10 10
5 5 5

variable4
1 1 1
2 2 21
3 3 3
```

the output is

```
variable1
10 20 30
40 50 60

variable2
2 4 40

variable4
2 2 21
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on one interpretation of your requirements:

```
awk '(NF<3) || ($3 > 20)' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your revised input:

```
awk 'NF<=1 || (NF==3 && $3>20)' input
```

This will print a line if it is empty, only contains one word (=header line), or contains three fields with the third one larger than 20.

**Edit** Your last revision to the question made this answer obsolete. Refer to [@Bodo's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/633363/377345) for an `awk`-based solution which fulfills your requirements.

Comment: this prints  all the headers.  What if  header one does not have a match, I dont want that to be printed.

Comment: @ak23456 please edit your question and make sure you are actually giving all the relevant information. We cannot guess what you need, you need to explain it to us. Otherwise, we will waste your time and ours giving you solutions that don't work. Make sure your example input covers all cases so we know what you want.

Comment: updated . sorry for the inconvinience